# How to check if csrf token is mismatch in back end?

Tags: laravel, csrf

Is there a way in Laravel 5.3^ to check if token is mismatch

for example something like this:

```
if (csrf_token mismatch) {
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Did you try autoloading app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Kernel.php, your middleware groups are defined. Add Verify CSRF token routine there. See the below example...

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

Then add VerifyCsrfToken.php in your app/Http/Middleware/

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];
}
```

You can also makes exceptions by specifying paths in `protected $except` array.

**CSRF token verification**

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');

    return $request->session()->token() == $token;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do i get if i do that??

Comment: My question is actually How does Laravel backend know that the token is a mismatch???

Comment: Laravel uses token in session to compare with posted token along with the form. I have added laravel token matching function for reference.

Comment: So if Session is expired there is no Token in backend right?

Comment: Correct and therefore token won't match and token mismatch exception will be thrown.

Comment: OK now i have learned that request doesn't even get to the controller function...if a token is mismatch it gets caught somewhere before

Comment: Its true... middlwares are like onion layers. It encapsulate the application and once its condition is satisfied, it passes control along to the next layer which can be another middleware with a different condition or controller like in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139304/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-rahi).

Comment: Doesn't above tokenmismatch() suffices your need? This does tell how tokens are compared and explains behavior on mismatch.

Comment: it's tokensMatch() function....you have overwritten the basic function and with that i think the csrf protection doesn't work as it should....

Comment: The above function was just a reference as your original question is how laravel backend checks token mismatch.

Comment: OK true....but i would like to discuss it more with you if you can open the chat?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this,

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->back();
        }
```

Comment: this is promising, i need to check it

Comment: as soon as I test it i will leave a feedback and if it's good this answer will be accepted!!

Comment: I have just tested it and i still get the token mismatch exception error

Comment: `if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
    dd($exception);    
}` it doesn't get inside

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished in the default middleware VerifyCsrfToken which is automatically included in the web middleware group.  More info on it can be found in the [CSRF protection documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf).

If you want to redirect back with a specific error message place the following in the render function located in app/Exceptions/Handler.php:

```
if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException)
{
    return back()
        ->with('message', 'Your message here.');
}
```

Comment: OK, but this is not an answer...it's just a comment ;)

Comment: It's actually both but perhaps rather than arguing semantics you should be more specific with what it is that you're actually looking for.  Do you want to override the existing middleware functionality which has been well-documented?  Do you want to know how the middleware is able to be included/excluded in a route?

Comment: Well i have some strange users that leave the page opened overnight and want to submit the form and they get token mismatch exception,,,,i just want to redirect them back if token is expired with message maybe

Comment: sorry but @ashanrupasinghe was first!

Comment: I noticed his/her post and updated with the means of providing a message and placing the code in a standardized Laravel location meant for this sort of thing.  But accept whatever answer you like; I'm more hopeful that it'll be useful info for people who may come across it in the future.

Comment: Thank you...that's the right spirit! There are people who get mad if you don't vote for their answer!

Comment: I made this function `if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
    dd($exception);    
}`

Comment: I came to a conclusion that if a session is expired you will always get token mismatch exception because there is no token in backend...so this can't be done in my case!